# _dispatch_assert_queue_fail crash on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-reports

I am getting a crash on our iOS app since iOS 14 hit the market.  The same app build on previous versions of iOS have NOT had the crash.

The repro steps are great:

1. Open a parent view
2. Open a child view, close the child view
3. Repeat 3-4 times, ending on the parent view
4. Wait for a period of time (generally less the 1 minute)
5. Crash (sometimes)

It appears to be crashing on a background thread.  I have looked for everything modifying the UI and cannot find any place we modify the UI in the background thread.

Any help with where to go next would be great.

```
CrashReporter Key:   cc7fbcbcf4da4c29df437fd10511467e7b461720
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,3
Process:             MyCompany [6775]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/MyCompany
Identifier:          com.mycompany.app
Version:             187 (13.1.187)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mycompany.app [886]


Date/Time:           2020-12-17 08:59:21.2352 -0600
Launch Time:         2020-12-17 08:46:55.3918 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.2 (18B92)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    6.02.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000001ad4751cc
VM Region Info: 0x1ad4751cc is in 0x1ad474000-0x1ad478000;  bytes after start: 4556  bytes before end: 11827
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      __TEXT                   1ad470000-1ad474000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...bobjc.A.dylib
--->  __TEXT                   1ad474000-1ad478000 [   16K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  ...bobjc.A.dylib
      __TEXT                   1ad478000-1ad4a6000 [  184K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...bobjc.A.dylib

Termination Signal: Bus error: 10
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process: exc handler [6775]
Triggered by Thread:  6

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libBacktraceRecording.dylib     0x000000010170579c 0x101700000 + 22428
1   libBacktraceRecording.dylib     0x0000000101705788 0x101700000 + 22408
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000102500954 0x1024c8000 + 231764
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024d1a20 0x1024c8000 + 39456
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a35d8c10 WTF::WorkQueue::dispatch(WTF::Function<void + 14765072 ()>&&) + 124
5   WebKit                          0x00000001a555c7a0 IPC::Connection::sendMessage+ 186272 (std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Encoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Encoder> >, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendOption>) + 768
6   WebKit                          0x00000001a57dcb20 WebKit::AuxiliaryProcessProxy::sendMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Encoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Encoder> >, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendOption>, WTF::Optional<std::__1::pair<WTF::CompletionHandler<void + 2808608 (IPC::Decoder*)>, unsigned long long> >&&, WebKit::AuxiliaryProcessProxy::ShouldStartProcessThrottlerActivity) + 508
7   WebKit                          0x00000001a57deae8 WebKit::DrawingAreaProxy::sendMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Encoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Encoder> >, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendOption>, WTF::Optional<std::__1::pair<WTF::CompletionHandler<void + 2816744 (IPC::Decoder*)>, unsigned long long> >&&) + 48
8   WebKit                          0x00000001a5830b24 WebKit::RemoteLayerTreeDrawingAreaProxy::didRefreshDisplay+ 3152676 () + 200
9   QuartzCore                      0x000000019cbf547c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items+ 78972 (unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 660
10  QuartzCore                      0x000000019ccc7268 display_timer_callback+ 938600 (__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 276
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a22b44 __CFMachPortPerform + 172
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a46410 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a45824 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 588
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a3f9e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2332
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a3eb90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001afd61598 GSEventRunModal + 160
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c328638 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c32dbb8 UIApplicationMain + 164
19  MyCompany                       0x0000000100879dd0 0x100794000 + 941520
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019971d588 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c4b6a644 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c4b69a48 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a450ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a3f560 __CFRunLoopRun + 1176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a3eb90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                      0x000000019ac5c7f8 -[NSRunLoop+ 30712 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6   Foundation                      0x000000019ac5c6d8 -[NSRunLoop+ 30424 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019c3d4438 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 504
8   Foundation                      0x000000019adb94bc __NSThread__start__ + 848
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d0b3c _pthread_start + 288
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d5880 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c4b6a644 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c4b69a48 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a450ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a3f560 __CFRunLoopRun + 1176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199a3eb90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000019a2ce720 0x19a09c000 + 2303776
6   Foundation                      0x000000019adb94bc __NSThread__start__ + 848
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d0b3c _pthread_start + 288
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d5880 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024cefdc 0x1024c8000 + 28636
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024cefd4 0x1024c8000 + 28628
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024cef64 0x1024c8000 + 28516
3   UIKitCore                       0x000000019c7eae5c -[UIImageView _mainQ_beginLoadingIfApplicable] + 72
4   UIKitCore                       0x000000019c7e3260 -[UIImageView setHidden:] + 72
5   UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcba228 -[UIButton _updateImageView] + 540
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcbabc0 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 348
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019c833288 -[UIView+ 17003144 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2468
8   QuartzCore                      0x000000019cd36b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 288
9   QuartzCore                      0x000000019cd3cff8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1421304 (CA::Transaction*) + 520
10  QuartzCore                      0x000000019cd48314 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1467156 (CA::Transaction*) + 140
11  QuartzCore                      0x000000019cc94570 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 730480 (CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 416
12  QuartzCore                      0x000000019ccbe6f8 CA::Transaction::commit+ 902904 () + 728
13  QuartzCore                      0x000000019ccbef04 CA::Transaction::release_thread+ 904964 (void*) + 228
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d5110 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 520
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d0b98 _pthread_exit + 80
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d28a0 _pthread_wqthread_legacy_worker_wrap + 0
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d2634 _pthread_wqthread + 416
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d5874 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d586c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c4b8e290 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001e00c0dec _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 192
2   MallocStackLogging              0x00000001c04d9220 uniquing_table_stack_retain + 1052
3   MallocStackLogging              0x00000001c04dad38 add_stack_to_ptr + 168
4   MallocStackLogging              0x00000001c04da11c stack_logging_lite_malloc + 276
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a84e69ac _malloc_zone_malloc + 144
6   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001e0059620 _Block_copy + 144
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024cbcb0 0x1024c8000 + 15536
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024cd734 0x1024c8000 + 22324
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024d0470 0x1024c8000 + 33904
10  libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00000001b2d6d72c 0x1b2d6b000 + 10028
11  libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00000001b2d6d550 0x1b2d6b000 + 9552
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024cd528 0x1024c8000 + 21800
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024d01cc 0x1024c8000 + 33228
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024e3a8c 0x1024c8000 + 113292
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024e0a5c 0x1024c8000 + 100956
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d25a4 _pthread_wqthread + 272
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d5874 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ad4751cc object_getClassName + 0
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024ff7c8 0x1024c8000 + 227272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000102500948 0x1024c8000 + 231752
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024e567c 0x1024c8000 + 120444
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024e5400 0x1024c8000 + 119808
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024edba0 0x1024c8000 + 154528
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001024e06f0 0x1024c8000 + 100080
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d25a4 _pthread_wqthread + 272
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d5874 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d586c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e00d586c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000153df4000   x1: 0x0000000153df4000   x2: 0xffffffff800010ff   x3: 0x00000000f8f80002
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000008   x6: 0x0000000117d0fb5c   x7: 0x0000000000159efd
    x8: 0x0000000000000100   x9: 0x0000000000000002  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000020
   x12: 0x0000002000000000  x13: 0x000000d100000000  x14: 0x000000015caaf3a0  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x00000001ad4751cc  x17: 0x00000001027b1818  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016f80a530
   x20: 0x0000000153df4000  x21: 0x000000010252c580  x22: 0x000000010252d080  x23: 0xffffffff800010ff
   x24: 0x000000000002ed2b  x25: 0x0000000153df4000  x26: 0x00000000000010ff  x27: 0x0000000fffffc100
   x28: 0x000000016f80b0e0   fp: 0x000000016f80a520   lr: 0x00000001024ff7c8
    sp: 0x000000016f80a4f0   pc: 0x00000001ad4751cc cpsr: 0x80000000
   esr: 0x8200000f (Instruction Abort) Permission fault

Binary Images:
0x100794000 - 0x100cbffff MyCompany arm64  <1f05dbb5cd933fb78beb5f0ffb47a8df> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/MyCompany
0x101700000 - 0x10170bfff libBacktraceRecording.dylib arm64  <7fd5bf987f933e618f51560a68fa4311> /Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib
0x101728000 - 0x10176bfff libMainThreadChecker.dylib arm64  <1ca5fde0040039aab056ef537de95613> /Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib
0x101894000 - 0x1018cbfff libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib arm64  <c43ef1193e543e80991ab37e6bf481f1> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
0x101900000 - 0x10190ffff Alamofire_Synchronous arm64  <062e9e24dd07351b96fbe1a87568959e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/Alamofire_Synchronous.framework/Alamofire_Synchronous
0x10192c000 - 0x101943fff FBLPromises arm64  <c7b3291d22483a55806acde09608c28c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
0x101968000 - 0x101973fff FirebaseABTesting arm64  <7b37f72950463230b61d2fefc5b773d0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseABTesting.framework/FirebaseABTesting
0x10198c000 - 0x1019a3fff FirebaseCore arm64  <4bc3d66fb5663df797c32467e52e5417> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore
0x1019c8000 - 0x1019d3fff FirebaseCoreDiagnostics arm64  <b2072ac5d92f3f6ba5eec3a4f26ad51b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
0x1019e8000 - 0x101a07fff FirebaseInstallations arm64  <03882e42b5063a0e97ebb119502c78c6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations
0x101a50000 - 0x101abbfff dyld arm64  <f756a8d55a803b4d996236fe0e7638c2> /usr/lib/dyld
0x101b3c000 - 0x101beffff Alamofire arm64  <a09a8e2516f133e48408286527fc17f1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
0x101d18000 - 0x101d73fff FirebaseCrashlytics arm64  <db2ca210246c305d867a21f8918c2733> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics
0x101dec000 - 0x101e17fff FirebaseInstanceID arm64  <3f3b05cb53503f7fbff612b457500942> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/FirebaseInstanceID
0x101e50000 - 0x101e77fff FirebaseMessaging arm64  <7c0d52b76171337cba3666e58efddc67> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging
0x101eb0000 - 0x101ed7fff FirebaseRemoteConfig arm64  <1c17979d65af347294d10ca3edc7d33d> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework/FirebaseRemoteConfig
0x101f0c000 - 0x101f33fff GoogleDataTransport arm64  <b567b98393c53fc19e2e0551d5e62baa> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport
0x101f6c000 - 0x101f93fff GoogleUtilities arm64  <8cdbd21cb80f363580ae3755ef416fac> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
0x101fc8000 - 0x1020e7fff MoPub arm64  <044ce2cc34b03d63953096588d2f64b2> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/MoPub.framework/MoPub
0x102278000 - 0x1022cbfff ObjectMapper arm64  <d5214b328fd6386aa93efd774efba869> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper
0x102330000 - 0x10239bfff SDWebImage arm64  <149490782fc83e12b0e1c99724182b1a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage
0x102438000 - 0x10245ffff SwiftyJSON arm64  <bf640f2209dd3689b086c365445dbcab> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
0x1024a8000 - 0x1024b3fff nanopb arm64  <5970c0d8d73a34a98b723e07fc0c1e2f> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AED62231-5C98-479E-8648-2DE8CCBD1ED4/MyCompany.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
0x1024c8000 - 0x10250ffff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <ec4afb1d05e832a68a70bbfd52351390> /usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib
0x102594000 - 0x1025b7fff DebugHierarchyFoundation arm64  <4d7f946b4ca83e7f8995e4c5ea5980e3> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugHierarchyFoundation.framework/DebugHierarchyFoundation
0x104660000 - 0x10466bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64  <b8c2db0f13bb343d93d8e8c6f6cee07e> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x1046d8000 - 0x1046ebfff GAXClient arm64  <d474b09b292f326d9c229c9176ed5ebf> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GAXClient.bundle/GAXClient
0x19971c000 - 0x199752fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <e31c0887c99930479b80203248ec2396> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x199753000 - 0x1999aafff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <9fc7dac3deed3a479abbe36867045ba5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1999ab000 - 0x199d54fff CoreFoundation arm64  <96f8386dd88a3c89a323a17975c3317f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x199d55000 - 0x199eeefff CoreServices arm64  <dd083b6922803f7e913646c9246b4a9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x199eef000 - 0x199f37fff WirelessDiagnostics arm64  <fbd6e8b92c91309fa9c26c9653c8cb1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x199f38000 - 0x199fb0fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <75fec68015053f2e84dc4a0a8586c617> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x199fb1000 - 0x19a09bfff CoreTelephony arm64  <1491284f13863425978d2f39e060af95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x19a09c000 - 0x19a51dfff CFNetwork arm64  <e261fa7130e23e6a8db232ecf79b30bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x19a51e000 - 0x19abe3fff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <c67a2d7144153f82939965c3956520ae> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x19abe4000 - 0x19ac54fff Accounts arm64  <dac79be132833bf8918bbbdca7a51004> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x19ac55000 - 0x19aeeffff Foundation arm64  <f1bc26a1f5bb36f7a65ad5f232dbf902> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x19aef0000 - 0x19b253fff ImageIO arm64  <982bf9fe32a43e0b95d21a5c8d206947> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x19b254000 - 0x19b26cfff libCGInterfaces.dylib arm64  <e6ddc58214b83593ad32b8ef9da35b5d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
0x19b26d000 - 0x19b7fbfff CoreGraphics arm64  <9c095d1529953f9daf186a3a3d13a1f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x19b7fc000 - 0x19cbc3fff UIKitCore arm64  <71b59f6219da3cff89e1dacf333bab0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x19cbc4000 - 0x19cbe1fff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <7b14f8ae35623cc7926d086785c913ea> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x19cbe2000 - 0x19ce55fff QuartzCore arm64  <ca8f28fcac5b3015ae8c4f2c0102efb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x19ce56000 - 0x19cebbfff BackBoardServices arm64  <4f98188591a0352b809337236d822a02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x19cebc000 - 0x19cf43fff TextInput arm64  <1a8e17692974328eb137a99894619a83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x19cf44000 - 0x19cfabfff libusrtcp.dylib arm64  <38d49d34771036a6933f051f5fd93ef8> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x19cfac000 - 0x19d341fff AppleMediaServices arm64  <39ffde16f1543a68b2c4be56eca89663> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/AppleMediaServices
0x19d342000 - 0x19d4a5fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <191cea851b253208a4634707cf529728> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x19d4a6000 - 0x19d855fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <3e4b597efce53f3ea83095489114d8e4> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
0x19d856000 - 0x19d86afff UIKitServices arm64  <6cfeb1e50b2232a8a45133d5027c8543> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitServices.framework/UIKitServices
0x19d86b000 - 0x19d9b3fff Preferences arm64  <930c7b581c853df198797b670f87c45f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences
0x19d9b4000 - 0x19dbc2fff ContactsUI arm64  <e57806e602dd3bfa8d2e221a4b322002> /System/Library/Frameworks/ContactsUI.framework/ContactsUI
0x19dbc3000 - 0x19dd7cfff CoreText arm64  <6e6f5e0cd9e1304b83482c0b4ab2a7af> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x19dd7d000 - 0x19dd95fff ExtensionKit arm64  <cb5f54bf46473348bf62ab7275e6307e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ExtensionKit.framework/ExtensionKit
0x19ddaa000 - 0x19de27fff BaseBoard arm64  <7f0411a61fcc389aa498fbdbe078bbe3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x19de28000 - 0x19e03dfff CoreDuet arm64  <0e709564f48b3d798ad7abbd403a1251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x19e03e000 - 0x19e189fff Contacts arm64  <738a964f2592342c8cf8ed3df85a7fd6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework/Contacts
0x19e18a000 - 0x19f5eefff GeoServices arm64  <b325f8217862350fa5b1b5d434f423d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x19f5ef000 - 0x19f674fff CoreLocation arm64  <480e95ff24123860bc54c9c4ede7bbf4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x19f675000 - 0x19f811fff CloudKit arm64  <5ee14a0a271b378cbc357efd5ef1a33b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x19f812000 - 0x19fb7afff CoreData arm64  <512043667c483b36b1e02c95663aec71> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1a0764000 - 0x1a076efff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <a1566d3c40ca35409a4be98a484640a9> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x1a076f000 - 0x1a07adfff AppSupport arm64  <17db41b85aba31299c64512406a5e5d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1a07ae000 - 0x1a08cbfff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <1b9df1125b5e3efcb19ca301d7d2e3ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x1a08cc000 - 0x1a0938fff IMFoundation arm64  <7f1639eb9c5837819ad1522da82ab6cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x1a0939000 - 0x1a0a3bfff IDS arm64  <8ddeaeaa96da3c9b88ba4ca207e7ef54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x1a0a3c000 - 0x1a0b79fff Security arm64  <149f8d12822a31a198bf48ce690f678d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1a0b7a000 - 0x1a0f71fff MediaPlayer arm64  <a73f58a9bbe83ceab929dedef2c0d10c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x1a0f72000 - 0x1a0f89fff AudioSession arm64  <3236a3742eae394a96a2237aaf3b5f3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AudioSession.framework/AudioSession
0x1a0f8a000 - 0x1a1103fff AVFCore arm64  <8cdc508c3c8e336b9f29d32c4eedce43> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFCore.framework/AVFCore
0x1a1104000 - 0x1a1668fff Intents arm64  <f3199470a1173b99988709c323bcadaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Intents.framework/Intents
0x1a1669000 - 0x1a16b4fff TextInputUI arm64  <352b17033e9b33a18f516aee1ff5b146> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI
0x1a16b5000 - 0x1a19b2fff CoreImage arm64  <a5984c5ef0a53d98874cb0eaf2646a30> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x1a19b3000 - 0x1a1a6dfff ColorSync arm64  <037592c7bb1f32af921e472cf9a95b88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x1a1a6e000 - 0x1a1aa6fff CoreVideo arm64  <e2d305b72dbf3d3dad312315c9d43030> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x1a1aa7000 - 0x1a21c8fff MediaToolbox arm64  <7f5ea89db4bc3f6daf02b27a41f5902d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x1a21c9000 - 0x1a22bcfff CoreMedia arm64  <7f6e05169d013c1d97abfac25c60b10b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1a22bd000 - 0x1a2528fff AudioToolbox arm64  <49e931593939360bb0310716e712c473> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x1a2529000 - 0x1a2578fff CoreHaptics arm64  <cf8486abf83b3a7a8d4c47af334e51a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreHaptics.framework/CoreHaptics
0x1a2579000 - 0x1a25d5fff UserActivity arm64  <204eaf6b983f3b879576eddba86a425e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserActivity.framework/UserActivity
0x1a25d6000 - 0x1a26d7fff UIFoundation arm64  <89449f94ec45399cb82200e854334e0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x1a26d8000 - 0x1a26fdfff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <3536d46d36cd3af4b92c67e4bdebd8c6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1a26fe000 - 0x1a277afff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <edf3e843a62a3dd092ccebe94d5a83e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1a277b000 - 0x1a27c3fff RunningBoardServices arm64  <b10f31f81c803bc5a4f87e58d284400a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RunningBoardServices.framework/RunningBoardServices
0x1a27c4000 - 0x1a36fafff JavaScriptCore arm64  <0a413324bb1c3b0182117a3e55a9f115> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1a3c8e000 - 0x1a3d13fff ContactsFoundation arm64  <fcc7ad598bc8393191d6af0a15db9161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContactsFoundation.framework/ContactsFoundation
0x1a3d14000 - 0x1a3f38fff HealthKit arm64  <d30da3534de1340583bdcd924d6a5b76> /System/Library/Frameworks/HealthKit.framework/HealthKit
0x1a3f39000 - 0x1a3f5afff ProactiveEventTracker arm64  <fd944cb63edb38ac827a91b7262ed683> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProactiveEventTracker.framework/ProactiveEventTracker
0x1a3f5b000 - 0x1a3fa5fff Lexicon arm64  <6d531b4861bc332fb00b8a42e2778491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Lexicon
0x1a3fa6000 - 0x1a400efff PersonalizationPortrait arm64  <8bb6361b8a5030f289ffaaf8c8cb2e7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersonalizationPortrait.framework/PersonalizationPortrait
0x1a400f000 - 0x1a405bfff CoreDuetContext arm64  <8d8c5f76d56a3c5c9f433e44ec1fcad3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetContext.framework/CoreDuetContext
0x1a405c000 - 0x1a4102fff IOKit arm64  <c50846c1e80d37e886984cf410de47a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1a4103000 - 0x1a4112fff DataMigration arm64  <9bef406302373341973658d5fe3338ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x1a4113000 - 0x1a416efff SpringBoardServices arm64  <b44c661eec0f39e0872e7307a4afe679> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1a416f000 - 0x1a4180fff ContextKit arm64  <b5a6fc21557c37e2a2d0f29b943dd511> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContextKit.framework/ContextKit
0x1a4181000 - 0x1a43dafff CoreMotion arm64  <cd1f30042ba23375a217a01310cc1316> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x1a43db000 - 0x1a4511fff EventKit arm64  <184114113e0b34ada009e79f7a56ee66> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x1a4a31000 - 0x1a4ca1fff MediaRemote arm64  <72424f62d23434bfaee4de96abc09861> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x1a4ca2000 - 0x1a4e3afff CoreUtils arm64  <1430df995b78363e964565be13d50bbf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x1a4e3b000 - 0x1a4e50fff FamilyCircle arm64  <e02e84d2fbbb300bb49caae97f43379b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/FamilyCircle
0x1a4e51000 - 0x1a4ebdfff CoreSpotlight arm64  <9be37e0ee25136ee996bc6a6f6e835f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreSpotlight.framework/CoreSpotlight
0x1a5295000 - 0x1a541efff AssistantServices arm64  <680eea804df4372490c73ae967765f83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x1a541f000 - 0x1a54e0fff CoreUI arm64  <5d80f7fa7f2b39929905a3b22c641f29> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x1a54e1000 - 0x1a552efff SafariSafeBrowsing arm64  <c785e4c6fae03774bba068f7778542c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariSafeBrowsing.framework/SafariSafeBrowsing
0x1a552f000 - 0x1a5c5dfff WebKit arm64  <19789fd9109837b7b6399e4f0eb867d6> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x1a5c5e000 - 0x1a8006fff WebCore arm64  <cb20a111c82d3e17ab3a08002f1f0525> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x1a8007000 - 0x1a8064fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <448540b0eca03930b98b2d18101114d6> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1a8065000 - 0x1a8080fff CommonUtilities arm64  <3ffd6ea3f0683eb49ab5ba7f761201bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1a8081000 - 0x1a81e6fff IDSFoundation arm64  <9167012f8eb333858885825cc96089b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x1a81e7000 - 0x1a82e4fff IMSharedUtilities arm64  <429bb5ecefd63e00bf9853c8eec2ea22> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMSharedUtilities.framework/IMSharedUtilities
0x1a82e5000 - 0x1a8385fff CoreSuggestions arm64  <16a233726a913a77a08e8c624335b5f2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSuggestions.framework/CoreSuggestions
0x1a8386000 - 0x1a8420fff AddressBookLegacy arm64  <d040464b88cb343187a1d4339ab93540> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AddressBookLegacy.framework/AddressBookLegacy
0x1a8421000 - 0x1a8451fff UserNotifications arm64  <166b5573570d31148c448c2661204d60> /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
```

Comment: I guess you have a RunLoop (timer) that auto-fetches new data from the server, and most probably when he tries to update the view, he is calling the updates from the background thread. You have there `__CFRunLoopRun` and you have `mach_msg_trap`, which means the system is trapped and cannot perform the task on the thread that was given to it.

Comment: @kiwi131 You have call for UIKit on thread 3 and it's the main mistake: `-[UIImageView setHidden:]`, redesign it to be called from main thread.